How can I trigger a GitHub workflow on artifact upload in another repo?
In project A we push changes daily to branches that actions build and run regression tests on automatically.  The regression tests currently run in sequence in the same workflow, but as a separate step, on virtual hardware (Qemu) and now we want to trigger tests on actual hardware as well.
We had this idea about creating a project A-hardware-test template that we (and others) can fork for each hardware test system we build.  Hence we cannot rely on repository_dispatch in A to trigger workflows in A-hardware-test instances.  Is there a way of achieving this without polling (cron)?
Ideally, A-hardware-test instance should also be able to report to an PR that it's picking up jobs and have finished them.
Additional info: the build step use actions/upload-artifact@v4 so we had this idea about triggering on workflow A run id and artifact availability?  That way the hardware tests could start almost at the same time as the virtual tests run (since v4 artifacts are available before the run has completed.)

The short answer is that you can't trigger a GitHub workflow on artifact upload natively (you may do it through a customizable solution using the GitHub API through). For what I understand from your description, a workaround could be to use a reusable-workflow or a workflow_dispatch event, sending the artifact name as input (and other relevant data such as the repo owner of the fork) for the new workflow to manipulate them (download + other steps).

adding to @GuiFalourd, you can also use workflow_call , and wait for the build to complete then use the build output as env input (artifact name or Id) in your case and create a workflow with them.
